# No muestra el modal y no muestra error

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una función que recibe parámetros de un controlador, se supone que muestre un modal pero la función se queda en el método `send()`. Lo observé con la consola y trae en la `preview` el  `form` dentro del modal....pero el modal no aparece. La pantalla principal cambia su opacidad para mostrarlo y se congela

Código de la función PD: el parámetro si llega es el id del usuario.

```javascript
function btnRolesUser(id) {
  const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = base_url + "Usuarios/permisos/" + id;
  http.open("GET", url);
  http.send();
  http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("frmPermisos").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      $("#permisos").modal("show");
    }
  }
}
```

Código HTML del modal:

```html
<div id="permisos" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="my-modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
        <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Asignar Permisos</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="frmPermisos">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] con el que podamos comprobar el error?

Comment: Normalmente se especifica el `http.onreadystatechange` antes de hacer el `http.send()`. Aparte de eso, puedes decirnos qué valor tiene `this` dentro del onreadystatechange??